# Confused how ShrinkToFit works with text

Tags: display, text-formatting

In Mathematica 13, I would like to have text displayed in a rectangular area (that will later be included in graphics), where the size of the rectangle needs to be set in advance. If there's too much text to fit inside the rectangle, I'd like it to be automatically shrunk so that it does fit. (I'd also like to control the justification and so on while still having the text line breaks done automatically.)

I thought that the `ImageSizeAction -> "ShrinkToFit"` option for `Pane` was exactly what I needed. But I'm puzzled by what it actually does. As I increase the coded font size, more and more of the rectangle is filled by larger text as expected … to a point. But then as the coded font size increases further, for some reason less and less of the rectangle is filled, and the displayed font size becomes smaller and smaller again.

Why is it doing this? How can I make sure that most of the rectangle is used to display the text?

```
loremIpsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla a sem mattis, tincidunt sem eu, vestibulum quam. Integer sagittis nulla eget pretium accumsan. Proin rutrum bibendum lorem quis maximus. Morbi feugiat lobortis rutrum. Quisque imperdiet porta tincidunt. Integer egestas mi at odio accumsan ullamcorper. Nulla rutrum maximus tellus, facilisis fringilla sapien sollicitudin vel. Sed feugiat arcu at quam accumsan luctus.";
Manipulate[
 Pane[
  TextCell[loremIpsum, FontSize -> f ,
   FontFamily -> "Garamond", TextJustification -> 1, Hyphenation -> False, LineSpacing -> {1, 0}, Background -> RGBColor[0.9, 0.9, 1]]
  , {200, 300}, Alignment -> {Center, Bottom}, 
  ImageSizeAction -> "ShrinkToFit"]
 , {f, 8, 36, 1}]
```

Comment: It seems to work as expected without the `TextJustification->1` option

Comment: Even `TextJustification -> 0.9` looks OK.

Comment: That is bizarre—! `TextJustification -> 0.995` still looks good, `TextJustification -> 0.996` is back to weirdness….